# Test assumption of common baseline - Adersen-Gill Cox regression?

Tags: survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards, recurrent-events

I'm running a Andersen-Gill recurrent (multiple events) cox model and I want to test the assumption of common baseline across events. Is this as simple as entering 'event' into the model and checking whether it violates proportional hazards? Or should I run models with and without strata(event) and compare the goodness of fit?

Thank you.